# Problems deploying to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, primefaces

I'm currently developing a project on tomcat. So, it's common fro me to redeploy my `war`. Unfortunately, it's very often when the next thing happens:

1) When I undeploy from `manager-gui, it says that it cannot undeploy and I am forced to stop tomcat and manually delete folder of the app, that contains`WEB-INF\lib\primefaces.jar`.

2) When I deploy from terminal with curl to `/deploy?path=/path&update=true` it says OK -- successfully deployed, yet it shows 404 on `/path` and in webapps folder the situation is like in point 1, and the solution is the same.

Even though it's quite irritable, I can live with that. But I'm developing a production application and later on I'd like to not have this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: YOu can do one thing i.e auto deploying. For auto deploying you have to make war entry in server.xml file with Docbase tag.

Comment: Autodeploy is active by default. Place your war in webapps folder and restart tomcat. Context will be equals war filename.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know this. The problem is, I _redeploy_ my application and this shit starts. Not always, by the way, but very often

Comment: We never do a hot deploy in production…  fixes all these problems